# SQL: I am doing a join amongst three tables, but I want to sort one column by most recent date

Tags: sql

I am doing a join between three tables, but the value of date column should give just the most recent time. whats the best way to achieve that? Would appreciate some guidance on this

my current query is :

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM dbo.ISD_machines a
INNER JOIN dbo.ISD_systems b
    ON a.HOSTNAME = b.SYSTEM_NAME
INNER JOIN dbo.ISD_laptops c
    ON a.HOSTNAME = c.[NAME]

Table 1

id        location   date

LAP2000   Mumbai    13-06-2022 11:45:00
LAP2002   Chennai   12-06-2022 10:30:00
LAP2004   Delhi     12-06-2022 12:20:00
LAP2005   London    14-06-2022 12:15:00

Table 2

id        areacode  date 
LAP2000   340987    13-06-2022 11:49:00
LAP2002   632009    15-06-2022 10:12:00
LAP2006   112098    14-06-2022 17:12:00
LAP2004   BST3DE    21-06-2022 13:10:00

Table 3

id        city         date 
LAP2001   Dubai        13-06-2022 11:13:00
LAP2002   Adyar        15-06-2022 10:21:00
LAP2003   Birmingham   14-06-2022 09:32:00 
LAP2007   Seattle      15-06-2022 18:32:00

Final result:

id       location areacode date
LAP2002  Chennai  632009   15-06-2022 10:21:00
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Your sample data doesn't fit your query

Comment: Why using `LEFT JOIN` if the output you need is composed of the only row that is found across all tables?

Comment: apologies, I inserted the older version of the query. I've updated that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough reputation to comment.

All three tables have date column. In the result, which table's date column are you seeking? Is the goal to take maximum of any dates from any tables? Assuming this, you could perhaps use this as a starting point:

```
SELECT TOP 1    Machines.[Id],
                Machines.[Location],
                (   SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate) 
                    FROM (VALUES (Machines.[Date]), (Systems.[Date]), (Laptops.[Date])) AS UpdateDate(LastUpdateDate)) AS LastUpdateDate
FROM            dbo.ISD_machines Machines 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.ISD_systems Systems
                    ON a.HOSTNAME = b.SYSTEM_NAME
    INNER JOIN  dbo.ISD_laptops Laptops
                    ON a.HOSTNAME = c.[NAME] 
ORDER BY LastUpdateDate desc
```

Think of cases where two locations have most recent update date. That will then mean you cannot use `top` anymore.

Comment: do you think that if I use top it will only pick the location with the most recent date as well?

Comment: When using top, you get most recent date. It does not care about the location value. If you ever need to get most recent solution for each location, then top will not work. It will also not work accurately if there are 2 rows with exact most recent date